# How to hide the text behind the position fixed element in HTML

Tags: html, css

I need to hide the text behind the position fixed element. The text behind the element will not be displayed
Here is the HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

#fixed {
    position: fixed;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-color: rgba(255,200,200,0.5);    
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>The position property</h1>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
</br>
<div id="fixed">position: fixed
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: background-color: rgba(255,200,200,1);

Comment: Don't use an alpha value on the background color

Comment: you are using the opacity value `0.5` in your `background-color`. That is the reason you are able to see the text. Decide yourself what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

That's impossible not to show the text behind #fixed unless you give full colour to #fixed like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>

    #fixed {
        position: fixed;
        border: 1px solid blue;
        background-color: rgba(255,200,200);    
        width: 300px;
        height: 100px;
        top: 40px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <h1>The position property</h1>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
    </br>
    <div id="fixed">position: fixed
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Alpha is for opacity. So, it can show the element behind. So, If you want lighter colour you can change RGB property. (But not alpha property.)

Otherwise, you can make the text invisible with opacity property. But, all the text will not be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

**Change :**

```
background-color: rgba(255,200,200,0.5);
```

**To :**

```
background-color: rgb(255,200,200);
```